# cube algorithm not generatin cube p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using p5.js and WEBGL more info about it [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Getting-started-with-WebGL-in-p5)

I need to draw a Cube using coordinates(x,y,z)

The Function that draws it:

```
 function drawCube(x,y,z,L) {
    A = new ThreeDpoint(x,    y,    z  );
    B = new ThreeDpoint(x,    y+L,  z  );
    C = new ThreeDpoint(x+L,  y+L,  z  );
    D = new ThreeDpoint(x+L,  y,    z  );
    E = new ThreeDpoint(x,    y,    z-L);
    F = new ThreeDpoint(x,    y+L,  z-L);
    G = new ThreeDpoint(x+L,  y+L,  z-L);
    H = new ThreeDpoint(x,    y,    z-L);

    line(A.x,A.y,A.z,  B.x,B.y,B.z);
    line(A.x,A.y,A.z,  D.x,D.y,D.z);
    line(A.x,A.y,A.z,  E.x,E.y,E.z);
    line(B.x,B.y,B.z,  F.x,F.y,F.z);
    line(B.x,B.y,B.z,  C.x,C.y,C.z);
    line(C.x,C.y,C.z,  G.x,G.y,G.z);
    line(C.x,C.y,C.z,  D.x,D.y,D.z);
    line(D.x,D.y,D.z,  H.x,H.y,H.z);
    line(E.x,E.y,E.z,  F.x,F.y,F.z);
    line(E.x,E.y,E.z,  H.x,H.y,H.z);
    line(F.x,F.y,F.z,  G.x,G.y,G.z);
    line(G.x,G.y,E.z,  H.x,H.y,H.z);
}
```

But this is te result i'm getting:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing but E and H are the same point

```
E = new ThreeDpoint(x,    y,    z-L);
H = new ThreeDpoint(x,    y,    z-L);
```

I think you want H to be

```
H = new ThreeDpoint(x+L,  y,    z-L);
```